# The best approach to combine Web forms with Blazor

Tags: asp.net, webforms, blazor-server-side

**Situation:**
At company where I work, we are using a big application that was written in Web forms fifteen years ago. We would like to start transition to ASP.NET core Blazor. This means that the whole application must be re-written in this new technology.

**The problem:**
Since it is a quite big application, the programming might take up to two years. The old application is structured in several modules and my manager would like me to convert module by module in the new blazor application (which will be followed by testing). Once a module is programmed in Blazor, we would like that our old application redirects to the given module in the new application. This means we need to keep running both application at the same time during the transition period. Also, we need a way that when a user logs in the old application he is automatically logged in the new app.

**The question:**
Is it possible to allow this simultaneous login (share session) using the same domain (maybe virtual hosts where the new application is domainname.com/new)? What would be the best approach regarding the architecture of such temporary hybrid? How to configure the server? Has anyone had some similar needs?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm in a similar boat (granted our legacy system isn't even Web Forms - just a Web Site project in Visual Studio). How you'd go about it depends largely on how the users are authorised in your legacy system

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Basically, some VB code is written to check if the entered password matches the encrypted one in our Oracle SQL database. I am wondering if this is technically possible and if someone had similar troubles. Web forms in VB is a nightmare to maintain now...too many lines of code repeated for every page separately although it is about the same purpose.

Comment: Ahh, it sounds like you'd probably need to put some kind of session cookie mechanism in and then implement a check on that similarly to how you do the password check

Comment: You need to investigate a custom AuthenticateStateProvider - see the MS-Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I think this aproach should work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760200/how-to-extend-asp-net-web-forms-app-adding-blazor